# Searching ObservableCollection's elements in a string

Tags: c#

i am trying to search an observablecollection's items in a string.

I try  as in the below code.

```
        for (int j = 0; j < DBControl.Instance.SelectLanguagesFromDatabase().Count; j++)
        {
            if ( dominatorIntern.ProgrammingLanguages.Contains(ProgrammingLanguagesList[j] )
                ProgrammingLanguagesList[j].IsSelected = true;

    }
```

Here `ProgrammingLanguagesList` is an `observablecollection`, then i got an error saying

```
Error   8   Argument 1: cannot convert from 
'InternRegistration.ViewModel.SelectionItem<string>' to 'string'
```

here, dominatorIntern.ProgrammingLanguages is a string storing languages like c,java,c++ and ProgrammingLanguagesList is an observablecollection.With an example

if ProgrammingLanguagesList ={c,java,c#} and dominatorIntern.ProgrammingLanguages=c,java i want to ProgrammingLanguagesList[0].IsSelected = true; and ProgrammingLanguagesList[1].IsSelected = true; how can i do that?

Comment: Does SelectionItem have a way to get the underlying string?

Comment: Is the type of ProgrammingLanguagesList an array of `SelectionItem<string>`?

Comment: @Kevin Yes, i initialize as                                      string[] ListOfLanguages = {};
           ProgrammingLanguagesList = new SelectionList<string>(ListOfLanguages);

Comment: I believe my code below should fix it assuming you replace the ??? with whatever the string property is that represents the name.  Not knowing the properties of `SelectionList` I can't fill in that bit for you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code... it looks like `ProgrammingLanguagesList` is an array of `InternRegistration.ViewModel.SelectionItem<string>`?

You need something like this...

```
// replace ??? on the next line with your SelectionItem<string>'s property that 
//  holds the language name.
var vmLanguageNameProp = ProgrammingLanguagesList[j].???
if ( dominatorIntern.ProgrammingLanguages.Contains(vmLanguageNameProp )
    {
        ProgrammingLanguagesList[j].IsSelected = true;
    }
```

Also note that it looks like you are making a DB call for every loop iteration to get the count... you definitely don't want to do that if that is indeed what is going on there.